# Hide a checkbox from OnMultiChoiceClickListener

Tags: android

I have used [OnMultiChoiceClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener.html) in my project. The code and output will look like this [blog](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html) post. Here I want to hide first checkbox. (because first statement will be **Please select ...**, this one should not contain checked option). Is there any possibility to hide it friends.

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: make custom spinner.i.e custom list-view+ dialog.By that way you can easily controls the views in row.

Comment: @Indiandroid, I will try it friend, I just want to know is it possible to hide in this way or not, because I had spent near two hours to find this way, If I move other way it also will take time. That is why I am seeking answer on this one. Thanks.

Comment: yes u can hide the checkbox of your first row in getView method of lisview adapter.and you can also add ok or clear button to your dialog layout.